# What is the best way to have Firefox-specific CSS rules now after @-moz-document has been limited

Tags: css, firefox

`@-moz-document` has been a quite useful hack to target Firefox in CSS. For instance,

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    /* Firefox-specific rules */
}
```

But now since https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035091 has been fixed, the old hack does not work anymore in Firefox Developer Edition and I believe this patch will land in the stable version soon. So

1. As Far As I Understand, UA sheets are the ones come with the browser for default element looking but what are user sheets?
2. Are there any CSS-only alternative implementations?

Comment: @Sirence My WordPress theme causes some conflicts with [SyntaxHighlighter](https://ja.wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) so I had a simple fix using the additional CSS function. Adding JS means I'd need to modify the source code of the theme or plugin, which is something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `@supports` [feature query](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/08/using-feature-queries-in-css/) testing some specific vendor prefixed `-moz-` value, e.g.

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLzybN)

---

```
<p class="moz">Is it Mozilla?</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.moz::after { content: " nope."}

@supports (display: -moz-grid) {
   .moz::after { content: " yep!"}
}
```

Note that this method will work until that specific value (e.g. `-moz-grid`) is not removed from the vendor in the future and can be also used to detect other vendor values (like `display: -webkit-box` or `display: -ms-flexbox`)

Comment: As mentioned above, this is not a reliable method anymore, just tested the Codepen link (  Firefox 66.0.2 (64-bit) ) - and it displays "nope", so the alternative solution is to use this: `@supports (-moz-appearance:none)` instead of `@supports (display: -moz-grid)`.

Comment: `@supports (-moz-appearance:none)` still works in FF 75. Thanks, @Darko.

Comment: @oaklandrichie you're welcome, I'm glad if it helps.